# What is the fastest library for multiplying polynomials and multi-point evaluation over finite fields?

Tags: hpc, libraries

I am looking for a library (don't care about the programming language) that performs the following two tasks as quickly as possible:

1. Compute the coefficients of the product of a set of degree 1 polynomials
2. Evaluate a polynomial at a given set of points (multi-point evaluation)

Everything happens modulo some integer. I don't know whether it's relevant, but the points in step 2 always lie in an arithmetic progression. Can you recommend a library? I already looked at NTL, but it's multi-point evaluation seems to be O(n^2), not O(n log n).